# Struct initialization with char array outside a function

Tags: c

I have following `typedef struct`:

```
typedef struct
{
  E_Menus Menu;        // E_Menus is a typedef enum
  char *MenuStr[200];
  int CurrentItem;
  int ItemAmount;
  int ItemGap;
  int StartItemGap;
} T_Menu;
```

I want to initialize a struct of type `T_Menu` as a module variable (not local inside a function) as following:

```
char mBootMenuStr[] = {"some text"};
T_Menu mBootMenu = {eUI_BootMenu, mBootMenuStr, 1, 2, 1, 2};
```

But `MenuStr` makes me struggle. I get 2 warnings:

```
1    initialization of 'char *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] 
2    missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
```

**`MenuStr` should be a string with size `200` -> Means, the string has 200 chars.**

When I remove `MenuStr` it builds without warnings.
What did I miss? Is it impossible to do this outside a function?

**Reproducable example:**

```
typedef enum
{
  eUI_BootMenu,
  eUI_LoginMenu,
  eUI_HomeMenu,
} E_Menus;

typedef struct
{
  E_Menus Menu;
  char *MenuStr[200];
  int CurrentItem;
  int ItemAmount;
  int ItemGap;
  int StartItemGap;
} T_Menu;

char mBootMenuStr[] = {"some text"};
T_Menu mBootMenu = {eUI_BootMenu, mBootMenuStr, 1, 2, 1, 2};
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: `char *MenuStr[200];` defined `MenuStr` as an array of `200` *pointers* to `char`. It's an array of 200 strings, essentially. Is that what you intended?

Comment: You may want to use `char (*MenuStr)[200];` instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah no, I want a char array with size `200`. Did I defined it as an array of 200 pointers?

Comment: @Oka I added an additional example.

Comment: If you want an array in your struct, you must remove the `*`. But this will not help you with initializing it from another variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char *MenuStr[200];` is an array of 200 *pointer-to-char*.

The initializer in

```
T_Menu mBootMenu = {eUI_BootMenu, mBootMenuStr, 1, 2, 1, 2};
```

is treating `mBootMenuStr` and each expression after it as elements to initialize that array. The integer values of `1` and `2` are being used to initialize elements of type `char *`, hence the warning.

GCC gives a more detailed diagnostic:

```
ex.c:21:49: warning: initialization of ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   21 | T_Menu mBootMenu = {eUI_BootMenu, mBootMenuStr, 1, 2, 1, 2};
      |                                                 ^
ex.c:21:49: note: (near initialization for ‘mBootMenu.MenuStr[1]’)
ex.c:21:52: warning: initialization of ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   21 | T_Menu mBootMenu = {eUI_BootMenu, mBootMenuStr, 1, 2, 1, 2};
      |                                                    ^
ex.c:21:52: note: (near initialization for ‘mBootMenu.MenuStr[2]’)
ex.c:21:55: warning: initialization of ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   21 | T_Menu mBootMenu = {eUI_BootMenu, mBootMenuStr, 1, 2, 1, 2};
      |                                                       ^
ex.c:21:55: note: (near initialization for ‘mBootMenu.MenuStr[3]’)
ex.c:21:58: warning: initialization of ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   21 | T_Menu mBootMenu = {eUI_BootMenu, mBootMenuStr, 1, 2, 1, 2};
```

This warning can be resolved by placing braces around `mBootMenuStr`, making it the sole initializing element for the `MenuStr` member of the structure:

```
T_Menu mBootMenu = {eUI_BootMenu, {mBootMenuStr}, 1, 2, 1, 2};
```

But it seems likely you simply wanted a string member, not an array of pointers, in the structure:

```
typedef struct
{
  E_Menus Menu;
  char MenuStr[200];
  int CurrentItem;
  int ItemAmount;
  int ItemGap;
  int StartItemGap;
} T_Menu;

T_Menu mBootMenu = {eUI_BootMenu, "some text", 1, 2, 1, 2};
```

Comment: The last option should be the right answer. If the OP does not want to repeat the string throughout the code, he can use a `define` for it instead of using a module/global variable

Comment: Another option is to really only have a char pointer in the struct, possibly to const char (if the OP doesn't need to change the text once it's initialized, which is well possible with menus). Having a pointer leaves the struct small enough that it can be easily copied (even though the shared string pointed to then is a resource issue).

Comment: Alright, yeah I didn't mention in the first place, that I want a string with size `200`. So I would use your 2nd example. If I want to use a variable instead of the plain string, I have to use `memcpy` or `strcpy()`, right?

Comment: @puncher Yes, you would have to copy the contents to the buffer at runtime. Attempting to initialize an array (say `dest`) via another array (say `source`) causes the source array to *decay* to a pointer to its first element, and that pointer value would be used to initialize `dest[0]`.